# InDesign CC 2015 Problem: Changes in one paragraph style applies to all

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles

I am pretty new to the program and i just learned the whole paragraph styles option. It worked great but I don't know what I did and now when I change anything to one style it applies to all, and i did check that the text is still in different styles.

In this case i am trying to change the leading of the headline but it changes also the one to the text body, this applies to justification, vertical scale etc.

Please help on how i can fix this!

[image]

Comment: This is probably the case because you have the paragraph style applied to the headline and the text body.

Comment: I checked and unfortunately it doesn't seam to be it.

Answer (score 4):

Your plain text style may be based on your heading style. As long as the derived style has exactly the same setting as its parent, changes in the parent are applied to the derived style as well.

Answer (score 0):

This same thing happened to me and changing the parenting fixed it. go to you paragraph style options> general> change based on> [no paragraph style]